# Is there any way to configure the <server> element in maven's settings.xml to use LDAP for authentication?

Tags: maven, ldap

Currently we're using the maven generated tokens for the password in each  configuration but there is concern that because we have a very aggressive password changing policy there are too many places to be configuring these new passwords. Is there any way to integrate maven and LDAP for the purpose of deployment?